# Filter a view by clicking on a link on another view

Tags: 7, views

I have been searching all over the internet for a solution to my requirement with no success at all.

I am working on a Drupal 7 website using the latest version of views where i have one content type under the name of **Hotel Room** which contains the below fields:

- Title (= Room Nbr)
- Room images
- Room description
- Room Size
- Floor Nbr
- Bed Nbr

1) View name: View A

I have created a **block** view of format **fields** and displaying only the **content:title** of the content type **Hotel Room**

2) View name: View B

I have created another **block** view of format **table** and displaying all the fields available for the content type **Hotel Room**

3) I have placed both views on the homepage,
where the View A is placed above View B.

4) What i need to accomplish is:

When i click on any **Title** inside the **View A**, **View B** will show me all the information related to the clicked **title**.
And of course without the page being reloaded .

Here is an image describing what i need:
[image]

On the above image:

when i click on Room Nbr 18 inside View A, all the details about that Room Nbr will show up inside the below View (View B) without reloading of the page.

**Update:**
The below image is what exactly i am trying to achieve in my drupal 7 website.

[image: Live Example]

Is that possible to be done using Drupal 7 and views ?

Any help is much appreciated...

Thank you !

Comment: "without reloading the page"... do you mean with Ajax?

Comment: Views Attachment Displays have the options to inherit contextual and exposed filters from the Views Display they are attached to. But it sounds like your situation doesn't require 2 Views. What you labeled as "View A" is actually just an Exposed Filter for field Title that you want to style in a particular way. You can adjust Exposed Filter settings to Autosubmit so the results change each time you change the Exposed filter.

Comment: @longboardnode yes i mean with ajax

Comment: @prkos you are right about the view A, but my problem is i want to add other field to view A and not only the Title field and exposed filters doesn't allow to do that. For example i would like the view A to have a title field, a background images field and so a tag field and the view B will be filtered by clicking on the link of the title field inside view A

Comment: @prkos can you please give me instructions on how to accomplish my need using views attachment ?

Comment: Just to clarify, both View A and View B will be filtered by the Room number?

Comment: @prkos no actually View A will be the filter of view B so by other words, View A will have a grid display of all available room number and when a room number is clicked, the view B will display information about the clicked room number only. Please note that creating both of views is easy for me, onky the issue is how to link them together or maybe how to pass argument from view A to view B ?... Thank you

Comment: It's still not clear why View A exists as a separate View. Will it only show room numbers to be used as a filter, or will it also show background image and a tag? If Room number is used as an Exposed filter then it will reduce the Views A list too. I guess you want the Jump menu option from Drupal 7 to filter one view with another, where the Whole Views A Results will be used to click on. In that case Argument Display won't help. I'll see if I can answer for the Jump menu solution.

Comment: @prkos The reasons behind why i need View A to be a separated view are because 1) i want to add more than one field the View A like Image field, taxonomy field, date field, etc but those fields will not be used for filtering but only for user information... 2) i would like to theme the view A in a way to load different css classes depend on each taxonomy term. As you mentioned in your last comment, Views A will only be used to click on any title link in order to filter the View B. Check my question on the views issue page: https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/2979534

Comment: Yes I see, I think the Jump menu might help, although I haven't tested it myself. Add the new image to your question, it helps to clarify why you want two views.

Comment: @prkos to be honest this is my first time i hear about the jump menu, however i was taking a look on the module page and i did not really understand how such module could help my case ?! Could you please be kind and give more info ? If you see it to fit my needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several considerations in your question, using Ajax, filtering one view with another, displaying Exposed filter as a grid. Since you posted your desired goal I'll address it directly without much discussion about various issues raised.

To achieve this in D7 you need:

- [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference),
- [Views Reference Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_filter) and
- [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters).

### Filtering one View with another View

1. Create Views of type Content showing Hotel room nodes.
2. Add Fields you want to be used in View A, as information for the filter
3. Add Entity reference Display to the Views and configure it to use at least one field (Title for example)
4. Save the View
5. Edit the View again and add Page display, configure the Path, and add the Fields you want in View B
6. Add a new Filter **Content: Nid (reference filter)**, expose it to visitors, and set the **View used to select the entities** to the Entity reference Views display we created in above steps. (It will be available as a choice if you saved the View after creating it.)

You should now have the Dropdown of your Hotel info from View A, and when you choose one choice from it, it will update the View B to show only that Room info.

Next we make it display in a list.

### Style it a little more closer to grid

1. Change `Exposed form style:` from Basic to **Better Exposed Filters** and configure it:
   **Autosubmit**
   **Hide submit button**
   Under `Display "nid_entityreference_filter" (Filter label: "Nid (reference filter)") exposed filter as` select **Checkboxes/Radio buttons** or **Links**, whichever you like best or you think would be easier to style

Now you have a list of all your node titles, with additional information, and when you click on one, the results at the bottom will automatically update to show only that one room info.

You can use CSS in your theme to style it more like a grid from your screenshot.

If you don't want all the room results before a choice is clicked use the option **Require input before results are shown**.

---

Jump menu can be used as a method for filtering one view with another, but it won't be styled more easily to match your desired theme (it's a drop-down) so i won't document it here.

Comment: i read about such method somewhere around the web but i never thought about the better exposed filter module to chanhe the style from drop down list into links and then style them ! Anw, i will for sure try your answer later today and will let you know the results. Thank you for your kind help

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help on the above subject, now everything is working as i imagine it. However, for later reference, i suggest you to remove "step 1 & 2" from the "Filtering one view with another View" section as they are useless. Also, please add to your answer one more step: change the "use ajax" option under advanced tab to "Yes" so the "page view" will be updated without page refreshing. Thank you again for your support

Comment: Better exposed filters changes how the options inside filters are displayed (radio buttons or links), and it make it work without a Submit button, as soon as you click on an option. The Ajax part that doesn't reload the page actually comes from the Views Reference Filter. You don't have to "Use AJAX" on your Page view for this to work (you can enable it if you need it for other parts of your Views). Your question was very specific referring to content types, so I included steps 1 and 2 even though you probably already have them.