# How to group view by field and display row results below?

Tags: views, 8, entities, hooks

We have a content type `Basic Page` that is supposed to be grouped by a taxonomy term field `Page Type` that has the following values below in a view.

How can we setup the view so that the view will display the `Page Type` in one group and the results in another group? Is this even possible without a `hook_preprocess_hook()` or custom `twig` template?

View Setup:

- Display: Block (`block_1')
- Format: Unformatted
- Format Setting: Grouping field nr. 1: `Page Type`, `User rendered output to group rows = true`
- Show: fields
- Show Settings: Inline fields --> `Page Type`
- Fields: `Page Type`, `Title`, `field_description`
- Filter Criteria: `Published = true`, `Content type = Basic Page`
- Sort Criteria: `Page Type (asc)`

`Page Type` Values:

- Blog
- Press Release
- Video
- Document

Current results:

```
<section class="views-content">
  <div class="view-row">
    <div> Blog </div>
    <h3> Page Title1 </h3>
    <div> Continually negotiate bleeding-edge materials through installed.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-row">
    <div> Blog </div>
    <h3> Page Title2 </h3>
    <div> Collaboratively disseminate global customer service for..</div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-row">
    <div> Blog </div>
    <h3> Page Title3 </h3>
    <div> Continually evolve enterprise-wide total linkage through..</div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-row">
    <div> Press Release </div>
    <h3> Page Title4 </h3>
    <div> Energistically productize competitive sources after standards..</div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-row">
    <div> Video </div>
    <h3> Page Title5 </h3>
    <div>Professionally implement principle-centered portals without efficient..</div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-row">
    <div> Video </div>
    <h3> Page Title6 </h3>
    <div> Uniquely fabricate high-quality testing procedures with..</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Desired results:

```
<section class="views-content">
  <div class="view-groups">
    <div> Blog </div>
    <div> Press Release </div>
    <div> Video </div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-row">
    <h3> Page Title1 </h3>
    <div> Continually negotiate bleeding-edge materials through installed.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-row">
    <h3> Page Title2 </h3>
    <div> Collaboratively disseminate global customer service for..</div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-row">
    <h3> Page Title3 </h3>
    <div> Continually evolve enterprise-wide total linkage through..</div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-row">
    <h3> Page Title4 </h3>
    <div> Energistically productize competitive sources after standards..</div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-row">
    <h3> Page Title5 </h3>
    <div>Professionally implement principle-centered portals without efficient..</div>
  </div>
  <div class="view-row">
    <h3> Page Title6 </h3>
    <div> Uniquely fabricate high-quality testing procedures with..</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve isn't grouping by a field, it is displaying the same node list twice, showing different node information in the two instances.

You can achieve it by creating two Displays in your Views where one is showing only `Page Type` field, and the other is showing `Title` and `field_description` while sharing the same Filters.

If your original View is a Page Display, it makes sense to use Attachment Display for the other. You adjust the Attachment to appear Before or After the other Display results, depending on which you created first. You could also make one or both of them Block Displays and place them one below the other in the Content region of your theme.

You could also render one View Display into another Display Header, with the help of an additional module [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view).

Your HTML won't be exactly the same as in your question, but it will be close enough, and you can override the templates in your theme for those particular views displays to achieve exactly the output you want. Attachment views usually show with their own class and `view-row`s outside the `.views-content` of the Display they're attached to, but if you really need to you can override them and set your own classes.

### Drawing from Drupal 7 solution

I posted an answer to a similar question for Drupal 7: [Filter a view by clicking on a link on another view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263004/filter-a-view-by-clicking-on-a-link-on-another-view). It doesn't completely mirror to D8 but with Better Exposed filters you can make an exposed filter behave similar to tabs, if you use Autosubmit optin and hide the Submit button.

### Taxonomy summary through a Contextual filter

One additional way of listing only the terms used on nodes in Views results is by creating a Summary through a Contextual filter.

1. On your Content Views Page add a Relationship to the `Page Type` field, you may require it since none of your results will have it empty.
2. Then add a Contextual filter **Term ID** from `Taxonomy term` Category and set it to use the Relationship from above, and these options:
   `When the filter value is NOT in the URL`
   **Display a summary**
   **Descending**
   **Number of records**
   `Base path` (if this is not the first Page Display in your Views)
3. Add Attachment View Display to this Page, keep all the options the same as in Page, only override the Contextual filter and remove it from Attachment.

This way you get the original list of nodes, after the terms relevant to the results.

The terms are already sorted by the number of results tagged with it. To make the nodes in the Attachment sort the same way use Aggregation on it.

Comment: we were able to use the attachment. The issue we ran into was that it was returning `Blog` (for example) for every `Basic page` that met the criteria. As a result we had to override the templates to get it to display just the grouping we need.

Comment: I woudn't expect any filtering issues here since it's a fairly simple case. Are you sure you have all the settings the same between the page and attachment Displays? Only the Fields that are shown should be different. Filters should be the same. Or maybe you have more than one node of the same term but you want the Attachment to only list it once?

Comment: I updated the example in the question to better show the results. You are correct in that the `attachment` view's filter criteria is meant to show multiple nodes of the same term so that we always group by `Page Types` that are linked to a node.

Comment: Heh yes, now the problem looks a bit different. You could possibly try Aggregation on the Display that lists only the Taxonomy terms. Or create a new Views block of type Taxonomy term that has the same Filters applied (through Relationships to Content) so you get the accurate term set, maybe even clone the default Taxonomy Views that is of type `Content` and adjust the filters there to show the terms. Is it important to keep the terms list "linked" to the results, so it only shows the terms that had been used in results? I guess it depends on what you mean by "group by term".

Comment: everything in the `<div class='view-groups'>` should be returned based on the results. `Group by term` is meant to mean that we will display all `Blog` results with each other (e.g. `Page Title1, Page Title2, Page Title3` are listed together since they are blogs, but `Page Title5 and Page Title6` display below that). Since `Blog` is listed first in the `view-groups` we want the result set to have `Page Title1, Page Title2, Page Title3` to be listed first as well.

Comment: Is the order important in itself, or only that it matches between two displays? The perfect solution might be to use Summary option through a Contextual filter, only it's usually sorted alphabetically or by number of results in each category.

Comment: Yes, the order is important as the `<div class='view-groups'>` will be displayed as tabs. When the tabs are clicked, then the content below will switch to the result set where `type = <select tab>` (for example). The view sort criteria needs to be kept. Thinking further, the only way we see making this work `mytheme_preprocess_views_view` and custom `twig template`, which is what i was trying to avoid. In either way, your answer did get us closer to making it work.

Comment: You haven't mentioned if you already have the tabs javascript ready, is the HTML output the only thing you need? Maybe there is a way to solve it without custom code, using only Views and Rewriting output a bit. I recently posted an answer to a similar problem but for D7, with the help of some extra modules but no custom code [Filter a view by clicking on a link on another view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263004/filter-a-view-by-clicking-on-a-link-on-another-view).

Comment: In that answer you recommended to use a `Better Exposed Filter` (I can't believe I didn't think of that). Using `twig` and `css` I modified the exposed filter to get what I need. Would it be possible to modify your answer to reflect the exposed filter suggestion, I can mark it appropriately as it is closer to what I was looking for?

Comment: I added the suggestions to my Answer for completeness, even if you already solved the html in your own way.

Comment: I ended up using your answer and was able to get rid of my custom code :-)