# How to get view pager url in node page?

Tags: 7, views

How to get pager url in node page ,actually what i want i am creating a view block with listing of nodes with ajax in view exposed filter,because exposed filter doesnt work without ajax,the problem i am facing when i am clicking pagination of view url is not creating like /system-manager/central-ordering/?page=1 .

Also used quick tabs where i am showing view as block in tab.

What i want when user click on the node in view page to see the node content ,i am placing there back button but on clicking back button everytime its going to pager 1(/system-manager/central-ordering) ,not on the same pager from where its clicked(/system-manager/central-ordering?page=3) .

Is it possible to add pagination in view url argument with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is showing node content by clicking on node title or similar, you can use the [Views Reference Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_filter) filter instead of the Exposed filter. It basically filters one View display with another display. You create one display with a list of node titles, another view display showing node content and add the special filter to the second display. This makes for a very nice user interface for instant filtering.

You can use this answer to a similar case to compare and follow steps: [Filter a view by clicking on a link on another view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/263004/filter-a-view-by-clicking-on-a-link-on-another-view/263339#263339)